# Extrapolation of area for a 2D integration

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a set of points distributed almost uniformly in a certain area of a 2D plane as follow:

[image]

An example of data points (orange)

> data =  {{0.919443, 1.68921*10^-22}, {0.262277, 1.46747*10^-22}, {0.100029, 
>     1.79784*10^-22}, {0.306084, 1.28699*10^-22}, {0.112433, 
>     1.73655*10^-22}, {0.501103, 9.83318*10^-23}, {0.736534, 
>     1.26314*10^-22}, {0.211711, 7.86554*10^-23}, {0.995601, 
>     1.56851*10^-22}, {0.985103, 2.41122*10^-22}, {0.091932, 
>     1.07448*10^-22}, {0.863752, 2.28541*10^-22}, {0.0351302, 
>     1.88604*10^-22}, {0.93385, 1.461*10^-22}, {0.0893479, 
>     1.59828*10^-22}, {0.484999, 2.29051*10^-22}, {0.881301, 
>     1.68107*10^-22}, {0.0122147, 1.60659*10^-22}, {0.687215, 
>     1.11088*10^-22}, {0.543829, 1.77277*10^-22}, {0.00937868, 
>     1.54779*10^-22}, {0.310382, 1.30057*10^-22}, {0.0996363, 
>     1.36884*10^-22}, {0.359278, 1.81618*10^-22}, {0.780102, 
>     1.48566*10^-22}, {0.685947, 1.75181*10^-22}, {0.414034, 
>     2.10908*10^-22}, {0.337114, 2.19492*10^-22}, {0.064049, 
>     1.26846*10^-22}, {0.0254781, 1.34605*10^-22}, {0.799211, 
>     1.47451*10^-22}, {0.109142, 9.03876*10^-23}, {0.847077, 
>     1.57622*10^-22}, {0.620951, 1.54069*10^-22}, {0.671867, 
>     2.2516*10^-22}, {0.79732, 1.36188*10^-22}, {0.389571, 
>     1.09633*10^-22}, {0.427064, 8.54728*10^-23}, {0.174333, 
>     1.18219*10^-22}, {0.69678, 2.0074*10^-22}, {0.569865, 
>     1.94722*10^-22}, {1.13945, 1.94502*10^-22}, {0.61084, 
>     1.80454*10^-22}, {0.661705, 2.23886*10^-22}, {0.723517, 
>     1.7212*10^-22}, {0.257577, 1.52795*10^-22}, {0.573445, 
>     1.42385*10^-22}, {0.0121323, 1.55767*10^-22}, {0.346676, 
>     1.14062*10^-22}, {0.402357, 1.35241*10^-22}, {0.0422658, 
>     1.95234*10^-22}, {0.197892, 1.89015*10^-22}, {0.58758, 
>     2.08242*10^-22}, {0.710434, 2.39968*10^-22}, {0.408211, 
>     2.4006*10^-22}, {0.766316, 1.4554*10^-22}, {0.717693, 
>     1.1791*10^-22}, {0.524029, 1.96709*10^-22}, {0.498814, 
>     1.53801*10^-22}, {0.837398, 1.4894*10^-22}, {0.161259, 
>     1.44629*10^-22}, {0.249881, 1.63788*10^-22}, {0.359329, 
>     1.41807*10^-22}, {0.891056, 1.49657*10^-22}, {0.752203, 
>     1.26999*10^-22}, {0.0366757, 2.30104*10^-22}, {0.869511, 
>     1.91538*10^-22}, {0.142483, 1.19818*10^-22}, {0.668088, 
>     1.31628*10^-22}, {0.752004, 1.09371*10^-22}, {0.756934, 
>     2.06303*10^-22}, {0.476383, 1.11862*10^-22}, {0.473173, 
>     1.06961*10^-22}, {0.0335032, 2.00627*10^-22}, {0.542263, 
>     1.96029*10^-22}, {0.14655, 1.22894*10^-22}, {0.252126, 
>     7.58905*10^-23}, {0.32622, 9.9375*10^-23}, {0.462346, 
>     2.06924*10^-22}, {0.681219, 1.79377*10^-22}, {0.0133101, 
>     8.13361*10^-23}, {0.152435, 2.06457*10^-22}, {0.25845, 
>     2.10363*10^-22}, {0.436824, 1.74233*10^-22}, {0.574122, 
>     2.163*10^-22}, {0.179385, 8.45847*10^-23}, {0.0782, 
>     1.60602*10^-22}, {0.0505291, 1.45056*10^-22}, {0.241452, 
>     1.63021*10^-22}, {0.11731, 1.28617*10^-22}, {0.54987, 
>     2.30381*10^-22}, {0.691911, 1.5518*10^-22}, {0.0968998, 
>     1.38005*10^-22}, {0.890343, 1.90565*10^-22}, {0.0386363, 
>     8.55301*10^-23}, {0.736979, 1.06244*10^-22}, {0.24687, 
>     1.90337*10^-22}, {0.121279, 2.25474*10^-22}, {0.507141, 
>     1.0407*10^-22}, {0.702705, 1.55965*10^-22}, {0.312321, 
>     1.47054*10^-22}, {0.49203, 1.09928*10^-22}, {0.945077, 
>     2.01756*10^-22}, {0.960104, 1.8587*10^-22}, {0.480353, 
>     9.58345*10^-23}, {0.538001, 2.31397*10^-22}, {0.945198, 
>     2.38312*10^-22}, {0.276567, 1.55793*10^-22}, {1.02113, 
>     2.30445*10^-22}, {0.568129, 1.5151*10^-22}, {0.0551225, 
>     2.2729*10^-22}, {0.939685, 1.81519*10^-22}, {0.14749, 
>     1.33573*10^-22}, {0.752361, 1.3417*10^-22}, {0.153348, 
>     2.09819*10^-22}, {0.578594, 2.08113*10^-22}, {0.0737863, 
>     1.92424*10^-22}, {0.557329, 9.9815*10^-23}, {0.775265, 
>     1.18665*10^-22}, {0.335795, 1.86232*10^-22}, {0.527896, 
>     2.34588*10^-22}, {0.473171, 1.58993*10^-22}, {0.0184686, 
>     1.03406*10^-22}, {1.0233, 1.31937*10^-22}, {0.42671, 
>     1.41831*10^-22}, {0.630073, 2.17127*10^-22}, {0.301462, 
>     9.73122*10^-23}, {0.760187, 1.67426*10^-22}, {0.40038, 
>     9.75316*10^-23}, {0.428928, 1.8046*10^-22}, {0.675504, 
>     1.84778*10^-22}, {0.25926, 1.98037*10^-22}, {0.231012, 
>     2.36719*10^-22}, {0.982679, 1.50415*10^-22}, {1.0495, 
>     2.12444*10^-22}, {0.667031, 1.54405*10^-22}, {0.12781, 
>     1.33258*10^-22}, {0.43549, 2.34414*10^-22}, {0.193757, 
>     9.77292*10^-23}, {0.139404, 1.24225*10^-22}, {0.728046, 
>     1.54744*10^-22}, {0.126039, 8.94785*10^-23}, {1.14527, 
>     2.14864*10^-22}, {0.304069, 1.30147*10^-22}, {0.537652, 
>     2.37965*10^-22}, {0.0130546, 9.85058*10^-23}, {0.42179, 
>     1.92653*10^-22}, {0.238706, 1.93927*10^-22}, {0.0703407, 
>     2.33258*10^-22}, {0.927644, 1.82092*10^-22}, {0.376465, 
>     2.06369*10^-22}, {0.842199, 1.17641*10^-22}, {0.127283, 
>     1.94166*10^-22}, {0.760772, 1.99594*10^-22}, {0.961883, 
>     1.98718*10^-22}, {0.42773, 2.14669*10^-22}, {0.331646, 
>     1.81976*10^-22}, {0.662338, 8.83718*10^-23}, {0.760104, 
>     1.21426*10^-22}, {0.0167881, 1.80345*10^-22}, {0.469549, 
>     2.19641*10^-22}, {1.07154, 2.06536*10^-22}, {0.165955, 
>     8.9077*10^-23}, {0.380123, 2.04375*10^-22}, {0.651594, 
>     1.19518*10^-22}, {0.893487, 2.36122*10^-22}, {0.987885, 
>     2.22763*10^-22}, {0.794042, 1.29503*10^-22}, {0.0107654, 
>     1.2722*10^-22}, {0.616735, 2.25487*10^-22}, {0.191093, 
>     1.5396*10^-22}, {0.55668, 2.35009*10^-22}, {0.295661, 
>     1.53958*10^-22}, {0.0779363, 8.26541*10^-23}, {0.140013, 
>     2.06211*10^-22}, {0.78031, 1.87112*10^-22}, {0.790181, 
>     1.87266*10^-22}, {0.299722, 1.58707*10^-22}, {0.513967, 
>     2.26839*10^-22}, {0.307952, 1.58816*10^-22}, {0.0521495, 
>     1.7687*10^-22}, {0.401584, 2.34159*10^-22}, {0.42395, 
>     9.02864*10^-23}, {0.343619, 7.46214*10^-23}, {0.554849, 
>     9.83958*10^-23}, {0.418084, 1.93555*10^-22}, {0.51792, 
>     1.5664*10^-22}, {0.505807, 1.59158*10^-22}, {0.294397, 
>     2.33655*10^-22}, {0.142263, 9.6198*10^-23}, {1.1119, 
>     1.99293*10^-22}, {0.120321, 2.04867*10^-22}, {0.681968, 
>     2.04214*10^-22}, {0.575389, 1.73157*10^-22}, {0.278575, 
>     9.07039*10^-23}, {0.595132, 1.28706*10^-22}, {0.275893, 
>     1.46673*10^-22}, {0.0873569, 1.97869*10^-22}, {0.513505, 
>     1.8021*10^-22}, {0.428456, 2.14228*10^-22}, {0.751676, 
>     2.2566*10^-22}, {0.953123, 2.09837*10^-22}, {0.127897, 
>     1.10151*10^-22}, {0.194148, 1.10899*10^-22}, {0.13999, 
>     1.94235*10^-22}, {0.377176, 1.88308*10^-22}, {0.714095, 
>     1.59165*10^-22}, {0.175542, 1.59964*10^-22}, {0.464467, 
>     9.30423*10^-23}, {0.0582835, 1.7147*10^-22}, {0.752472, 
>     1.34629*10^-22}, {0.320324, 2.40395*10^-22}, {0.627923, 
>     1.11389*10^-22}, {0.533403, 1.58098*10^-22}, {0.731927, 
>     1.48447*10^-22}, {0.139461, 1.83683*10^-22}, {0.611858, 
>     1.91878*10^-22}, {0.542112, 1.0246*10^-22}, {0.0329156, 
>     1.27751*10^-22}, {0.586546, 2.00978*10^-22}, {0.225169, 
>     1.51764*10^-22}, {0.495209, 1.85674*10^-22}, {0.102974, 
>     1.5402*10^-22}, {0.421391, 1.67543*10^-22}, {0.350901, 
>     1.2831*10^-22}, {0.415893, 1.09699*10^-22}, {0.100876, 
>     1.95942*10^-22}, {0.0286209, 2.03597*10^-22}, {0.509197, 
>     1.03704*10^-22}, {0.579875, 1.53778*10^-22}, {0.859368, 
>     1.91014*10^-22}, {0.120051, 1.86367*10^-22}, {0.276337, 
>     1.70985*10^-22}, {1.11855, 2.3233*10^-22}, {0.507144, 
>     1.56355*10^-22}, {0.0548121, 9.2178*10^-23}, {0.452492, 
>     1.74964*10^-22}, {0.569232, 1.51063*10^-22}, {0.312825, 
>     2.09341*10^-22}, {0.751054, 2.30745*10^-22}, {0.13785, 
>     1.28694*10^-22}, {0.628381, 1.31934*10^-22}, {0.911911, 
>     1.51446*10^-22}, {0.127206, 1.92571*10^-22}, {0.735407, 
>     1.79373*10^-22}, {0.881902, 2.01396*10^-22}, {0.864232, 
>     2.13593*10^-22}, {0.233701, 8.4474*10^-23}, {0.690529, 
>     1.52358*10^-22}, {0.473923, 1.62897*10^-22}, {0.409107, 
>     1.0637*10^-22}, {0.437484, 1.91276*10^-22}, {0.0454832, 
>     2.29823*10^-22}, {0.0597782, 8.52051*10^-23}, {0.282722, 
>     8.49879*10^-23}, {0.170361, 1.89839*10^-22}, {0.101389, 
>     2.40723*10^-22}, {0.885746, 1.7828*10^-22}, {0.585378, 
>     1.56675*10^-22}, {0.39993, 1.22881*10^-22}, {0.205006, 
>     2.25438*10^-22}, {0.809837, 2.29729*10^-22}, {0.409407, 
>     1.99033*10^-22}, {0.416072, 1.8825*10^-22}, {0.380218, 
>     1.33664*10^-22}, {0.677642, 1.08118*10^-22}, {0.323116, 
>     2.34079*10^-22}, {0.378026, 1.83097*10^-22}, {0.271065, 
>     1.33928*10^-22}, {0.532178, 1.16571*10^-22}, {0.321013, 
>     1.48832*10^-22}, {0.477291, 1.14755*10^-22}, {0.421012, 
>     1.29955*10^-22}, {0.700144, 1.13358*10^-22}, {0.162381, 
>     7.42761*10^-23}, {0.233104, 1.53395*10^-22}, {0.956974, 
>     2.22856*10^-22}, {0.249376, 1.1044*10^-22}, {0.0893579, 
>     1.5172*10^-22}, {0.338504, 1.86302*10^-22}, {0.265723, 
>     8.50596*10^-23}, {0.571793, 1.55783*10^-22}, {0.183851, 
>     1.92149*10^-22}, {0.270733, 1.10196*10^-22}, {0.731082, 
>     1.59755*10^-22}, {0.37419, 8.73417*10^-23}, {0.882102, 
>     2.39669*10^-22}, {0.783208, 1.38731*10^-22}, {0.717803, 
>     2.0131*10^-22}, {0.572485, 1.21024*10^-22}, {0.297554, 
>     2.36945*10^-22}, {0.507273, 8.56806*10^-23}, {0.625064, 
>     1.48485*10^-22}, {0.94486, 2.24114*10^-22}, {0.786714, 
>     2.33002*10^-22}, {0.337986, 1.97487*10^-22}, {0.688607, 
>     2.08231*10^-22}, {0.0914527, 1.0273*10^-22}, {0.995996, 
>     2.32627*10^-22}, {0.326543, 2.14683*10^-22}, {0.114373, 
>     2.39855*10^-22}, {0.436465, 2.23546*10^-22}, {0.471314, 
>     1.30661*10^-22}, {0.374965, 2.29788*10^-22}, {0.279905, 
>     1.43367*10^-22}, {0.911817, 2.21488*10^-22}, {0.505025, 
>     9.85307*10^-23}, {0.484578, 1.50992*10^-22}, {0.746232, 
>     1.5635*10^-22}, {0.589508, 2.03584*10^-22}, {0.437334, 
>     1.07104*10^-22}, {0.921845, 2.29176*10^-22}, {0.177797, 
>     1.52449*10^-22}, {0.0994191, 1.47968*10^-22}, {0.401122, 
>     2.24554*10^-22}, {0.875916, 1.91326*10^-22}, {0.641351, 
>     1.79951*10^-22}, {0.79726, 1.27162*10^-22}, {0.147254, 
>     1.40424*10^-22}, {0.426044, 1.86773*10^-22}, {0.245477, 
>     9.97371*10^-23}, {1.10187, 2.38428*10^-22}, {0.178528, 
>     1.82961*10^-22}, {0.771725, 1.40868*10^-22}, {0.241408, 
>     1.76892*10^-22}, {0.0912653, 1.85085*10^-22}, {1.02341, 
>     1.68935*10^-22}, {0.150533, 2.00321*10^-22}, {0.749221, 
>     2.23947*10^-22}, {0.197512, 1.19343*10^-22}, {0.905033, 
>     2.03187*10^-22}, {0.150528, 1.75136*10^-22}, {0.386613, 
>     1.98583*10^-22}, {0.286311, 1.8694*10^-22}, {0.108648, 
>     8.63373*10^-23}, {0.0287737, 2.30241*10^-22}, {0.175162, 
>     1.10322*10^-22}, {0.0841956, 1.84434*10^-22}, {0.0366108, 
>     2.38672*10^-22}, {0.580072, 1.40473*10^-22}, {0.700119, 
>     1.37588*10^-22}, {0.125274, 1.3038*10^-22}, {0.420081, 
>     1.17488*10^-22}, {0.678666, 1.13802*10^-22}, {0.399503, 
>     1.27142*10^-22}, {0.370554, 2.2662*10^-22}, {0.641952, 
>     2.02399*10^-22}, {0.322226, 1.24786*10^-22}, {0.661215, 
>     1.928*10^-22}, {0.344201, 2.31655*10^-22}, {0.828745, 
>     2.33846*10^-22}, {0.947324, 1.38386*10^-22}, {0.0326282, 
>     1.21098*10^-22}, {0.570852, 1.24092*10^-22}, {0.537027, 
>     1.26678*10^-22}, {0.887638, 1.54647*10^-22}, {0.550981, 
>     1.97548*10^-22}, {0.593818, 1.33339*10^-22}, {0.13198, 
>     1.15559*10^-22}, {0.158949, 2.32554*10^-22}, {0.305062, 
>     1.33678*10^-22}, {0.223316, 1.61175*10^-22}, {0.0808379, 
>     2.12948*10^-22}, {0.305859, 1.6661*10^-22}, {0.429248, 
>     2.03709*10^-22}, {0.163843, 2.22779*10^-22}}
>
> data2 = {{0.919276, 4.38735*10^-23}, {0.951896, 1.35155*10^-22}, {0.310916, 
>     5.10287*10^-23}, {1.23326, 2.34265*10^-22}, {1.04422, 
>     1.49503*10^-22}, {0.287862, 3.71991*10^-23}, {1.50058, 
>     1.46449*10^-22}, {0.00593375, 6.12249*10^-23}, {1.51683, 
>     3.67235*10^-23}, {0.886457, 4.204*10^-23}, {1.53503, 
>     1.35701*10^-22}, {1.09922, 1.35214*10^-22}, {1.33077, 
>     3.52159*10^-22}, {0.541356, -4.0609*10^-24}, {0.965739, 
>     1.71712*10^-22}, {1.38901, -3.64133*10^-24}, {0.938142, 
>     6.61387*10^-23}, {1.33043, 7.45194*10^-23}, {1.49287, 
>     3.63973*10^-22}, {0.327387, 3.3216*10^-24}, {1.03986, 
>     1.29551*10^-22}, {0.011981, 7.33329*10^-23}, {1.18633, 
>     3.46991*10^-22}, {1.04457, 1.0814*10^-22}, {1.52161, 
>     1.96358*10^-22}, {1.40517, 2.52532*10^-22}, {0.777592, 
>     1.65352*10^-22}, {0.463538, 1.05823*10^-22}, {0.910098, 
>     9.96362*10^-23}, {0.853597, 3.27208*10^-22}, {0.484687, 
>     1.30399*10^-23}, {0.328842, 5.42957*10^-23}, {1.18736, 
>     7.72801*10^-23}, {0.192066, 2.37633*10^-23}, {1.5524, 
>     2.3689*10^-22}, {1.25825, 3.29974*10^-22}, {1.27672, 
>     2.10942*10^-22}, {1.06657, 3.21239*10^-22}, {1.08566, 
>     3.22306*10^-22}, {1.43494, 3.58769*10^-22}, {1.05635, 
>     3.64574*10^-22}, {1.48416, 8.01699*10^-24}, {1.14596, 
>     9.44847*10^-23}, {1.50729, 1.84471*10^-22}, {1.31776, 
>     2.65801*10^-22}, {1.46403, 2.3376*10^-22}, {0.990116, 
>     1.03558*10^-22}, {0.315579, 8.09212*10^-23}, {0.799309, 
>     8.55292*10^-23}, {1.17836, 3.21071*10^-22}, {1.26918, 
>     9.82607*10^-23}, {1.49676, 
>     3.48146*10^-22}, {1.47651, -1.95079*10^-25}, {1.4041, 
>     5.41743*10^-23}, {0.387707, 4.9506*10^-23}, {1.50773, 
>     1.10067*10^-22}, {1.5086, 2.95238*10^-22}, {0.341351, 
>     6.99245*10^-23}, {0.265903, 3.17274*10^-23}, {0.881577, 
>     4.08668*10^-23}, {0.963586, 3.36197*10^-22}, {0.902919, 
>     3.63647*10^-22}, {0.426502, 2.32449*10^-23}, {0.73707, 
>     3.73398*10^-23}, {0.294292, 8.50212*10^-24}, {1.06473, 
>     8.88912*10^-23}, {1.40031, 1.44429*10^-22}, {1.34663, 
>     2.59281*10^-22}, {1.16074, 2.35922*10^-22}, {0.9698, 
>     3.41793*10^-22}, {1.02745, 3.32447*10^-22}, {0.809476, 
>     4.51641*10^-23}, {1.24542, 1.61928*10^-22}, {1.33362, 
>     2.09599*10^-22}, {0.919689, 2.15745*10^-22}, {0.794695, 
>     8.51344*10^-23}, {1.01039, 2.05981*10^-22}, {1.47456, 
>     9.43803*10^-23}, {1.06513, 1.4378*10^-23}, {1.56612, 
>     1.79919*10^-22}, {0.425546, 4.24979*10^-23}, {0.951008, 
>     3.75202*10^-23}, {0.837539, 3.66883*10^-22}, {1.39563, 
>     3.40863*10^-22}, {1.51405, 3.36902*10^-22}, {1.46324, 
>     1.32536*10^-22}, {0.737029, 7.89571*10^-23}, {0.658493, 
>     2.71626*10^-24}, {1.34137, 1.07606*10^-22}, {1.42026, 
>     1.38421*10^-22}, {1.0745, 2.04232*10^-22}, {1.42594, 
>     3.46287*10^-22}, {1.16243, 2.83492*10^-22}, {1.17524, 
>     1.17488*10^-22}, {0.752051, 1.76065*10^-22}, {0.413131, 
>     4.62403*10^-23}, {1.17012, -2.63236*10^-24}, {0.0815294, \
>   -6.07396*10^-24}, {1.41198, 2.87663*10^-22}, {1.56367, 
>     3.37516*10^-22}, {1.23591, 4.64113*10^-23}, {0.897326, 
>     6.09596*10^-23}, {1.24578, 2.37555*10^-22}, {1.44438, 
>     2.74215*10^-22}, {0.682947, 
>     4.08381*10^-23}, {0.374018, -3.71322*10^-24}, {1.43706, 
>     1.93492*10^-22}, {0.565316, 7.22229*10^-23}, {1.27103, 
>     1.09855*10^-22}, {0.875437, 2.7275*10^-23}, {0.195408, 
>     2.58126*10^-23}, {0.00278956, -8.50474*10^-25}, {1.10752, 
>     1.65042*10^-23}, {1.23232, 
>     1.35367*10^-22}, {0.173815, -4.26018*10^-24}, {0.229169, \
>   -7.01384*10^-24}, {0.257369, -4.69747*10^-24}, {0.794562, 
>     3.35383*10^-22}, {0.909665, 3.64627*10^-22}, {0.595369, 
>     2.16491*10^-23}, {1.31457, 1.36351*10^-22}, {1.37303, 
>     1.87626*10^-22}, {1.1427, 2.47963*10^-22}, {1.54332, 
>     2.83196*10^-23}, {1.01119, 3.54518*10^-22}, {1.22858, 
>     1.71288*10^-22}, {0.829228, 3.32034*10^-23}, {1.32786, 
>     1.48804*10^-22}, {0.822185, 7.17127*10^-23}, {1.49161, 
>     3.40309*10^-22}, {1.31733, 1.57369*10^-23}, {1.04949, 
>     9.48*10^-23}, {0.834378, 1.34727*10^-22}, {1.43868, 
>     1.96587*10^-22}, {1.55914, 2.76023*10^-22}, {0.452377, 
>     7.66928*10^-23}, {0.52462, 2.29565*10^-23}, {1.23659, 
>     2.58973*10^-22}, {1.2916, 2.84589*10^-22}, {0.980623, 
>     1.32425*10^-22}, {0.902437, 2.74504*10^-23}, {0.117391, 
>     4.69997*10^-23}, {1.44583, 3.55795*10^-22}, {1.27902, 
>     1.70943*10^-22}, {1.20522, 2.56076*10^-22}, {0.142422, 
>     2.17272*10^-23}, {0.852349, 1.67222*10^-22}, {0.752167, 
>     6.59946*10^-23}, {0.746175, 7.26869*10^-23}, {1.32418, 
>     3.60473*10^-22}, {0.1146, 1.88817*10^-23}, {1.36464, 
>     3.0941*10^-22}, {1.38043, 2.53914*10^-22}, {1.55994, 
>     2.63282*10^-22}, {0.398448, 1.27581*10^-23}, {1.20744, 
>     6.07146*10^-23}, {0.0228117, 6.74536*10^-24}, {0.938178, 
>     1.73819*10^-23}, {1.41388, 3.26869*10^-23}, {1.42817, 
>     2.23943*10^-22}, {1.54306, 1.29867*10^-22}, {0.405602, 
>     6.69858*10^-23}, {1.53895, 1.36523*10^-22}, {0.557242, 
>     2.29175*10^-23}, {1.15181, 1.18614*10^-22}, {1.22375, 
>     3.49465*10^-22}, {1.50854, 6.57211*10^-23}, {1.01911, 
>     3.36472*10^-22}, {0.350643, 
>     6.29874*10^-24}, {0.374775, -4.65047*10^-24}, {0.667673, 
>     1.34125*10^-22}, {0.860453, 3.45974*10^-22}, {1.50716, 
>     1.35565*10^-22}, {1.17377, 3.62593*10^-22}, {0.355702, 
>     2.18157*10^-23}, {1.32747, 1.61424*10^-22}, {1.54213, 
>     2.23014*10^-22}, {0.86313, 9.50568*10^-26}, {1.24664, 
>     1.0504*10^-22}, {1.19873, 3.10159*10^-22}, {1.49799, 
>     2.32501*10^-22}, {1.48155, 7.46827*10^-23}, {1.32969, 
>     9.95329*10^-23}, {1.18607, 2.61754*10^-23}, {1.1717, 
>     2.50121*10^-22}, {1.34012, 2.95342*10^-22}, {0.16206, 
>     5.54178*10^-23}, {0.387822, 4.81121*10^-23}, {1.06472, 
>     1.14764*10^-22}, {1.46799, 1.18264*10^-22}, {0.977478, 
>     1.17186*10^-22}, {1.23081, 2.88909*10^-22}, {1.36069, 
>     2.4277*10^-22}, {0.542923, 6.46332*10^-23}, {1.4729, 
>     6.11684*10^-23}, {0.617142, 4.33733*10^-24}, {0.141102, 
>     5.49726*10^-23}, {1.37402, 2.87344*10^-22}, {0.261944, 
>     1.27124*10^-23}, {0.0185916, 6.014*10^-23}, {0.948902, 
>     1.81993*10^-22}, {0.861479, 2.62094*10^-23}, {0.237276, 
>     2.04696*10^-23}, {1.007, 2.11793*10^-22}, {1.24083, 
>     5.75212*10^-23}, {1.39095, 3.35873*10^-22}, {1.44592, 
>     2.8995*10^-22}, {1.02598, 1.20647*10^-22}, {1.18686, 
>     2.96003*10^-22}, {0.0149602, 3.13188*10^-23}, {1.41001, 
>     9.2015*10^-23}, {0.952966, 4.84286*10^-23}, {1.49285, 
>     7.18499*10^-23}, {0.563216, 8.05842*10^-23}, {1.1467, 
>     3.55326*10^-22}, {1.00665, 1.30792*10^-22}, {0.551039, 
>     3.85599*10^-23}, {1.44415, 1.35486*10^-22}, {0.836782, 
>     3.06148*10^-22}, {0.973779, 9.11209*10^-24}, {1.16807, 
>     4.9574*10^-23}, {1.43602, 7.6555*10^-23}, {0.751628, 
>     1.8306*10^-23}, {0.624418, 5.59711*10^-23}, {1.34123, 
>     2.64996*10^-22}, {1.14959, 
>     1.0556*10^-22}, {0.781867, -7.08495*10^-25}, {0.0905615, 
>     1.50142*10^-23}, {0.925247, 2.61286*10^-22}, {0.287851, 
>     6.05552*10^-23}, {1.53137, 2.52408*10^-22}, {0.69254, 
>     4.01099*10^-23}, {1.48402, 1.75095*10^-23}, {1.50758, 
>     2.79213*10^-22}, {0.144449, 3.96753*10^-23}, {1.33887, 
>     2.77363*10^-22}, {1.54193, 8.8533*10^-23}, {1.56639, 
>     2.61185*10^-22}, {1.24106, 1.81631*10^-22}, {0.00301759, 
>     6.1946*10^-23}, {1.09511, 2.89406*10^-22}, {1.43023, 
>     2.15113*10^-22}, {0.179954, 5.04188*10^-23}, {1.35628, 
>     3.49271*10^-22}, {1.13554, 
>     2.51441*10^-22}, {0.523576, -1.07823*10^-24}, {0.978354, 
>     2.78424*10^-22}, {1.55413, 
>     2.50878*10^-22}, {0.149564, -7.27201*10^-24}, {1.30283, 
>     2.90667*10^-22}, {1.15839, 1.12242*10^-22}, {1.45482, 
>     2.61206*10^-22}, {1.39043, 1.78712*10^-22}, {0.0360668, 
>     6.61009*10^-23}, {1.5574, 2.61619*10^-22}, {1.0836, 
>     6.19294*10^-23}, {1.36217, 5.30049*10^-23}, {1.16214, 
>     3.29393*10^-22}, {1.08858, 
>     1.23152*10^-22}, {0.0839458, -7.41966*10^-24}, {1.56592, 
>     6.50801*10^-23}, {0.950586, 1.43415*10^-22}, {1.41449, 
>     2.69019*10^-22}, {1.06718, 8.14187*10^-23}, {1.40551, 
>     2.15752*10^-22}, {0.604388, -3.88908*10^-24}, {1.4115, 
>     2.38674*10^-22}, {1.20312, 5.06728*10^-23}, {1.41357, 
>     3.34922*10^-22}, {1.29404, 1.88062*10^-22}, {1.19659, 
>     2.94293*10^-22}, {0.500705, -7.96119*10^-24}, {0.432007, 
>     2.29249*10^-23}, {1.02653, 7.03095*10^-23}, {1.55493, 
>     1.15543*10^-22}, {1.31887, 
>     4.23438*10^-23}, {0.458125, -5.37021*10^-24}, {0.466947, \
>   -6.34671*10^-24}, {0.90572, 1.68503*10^-22}, {1.20019, 
>     1.00239*10^-23}, {1.31019, 2.42312*10^-22}, {1.03212, 
>     2.68188*10^-22}, {1.02035, 2.21987*10^-22}, {1.11636, 
>     6.24969*10^-23}, {0.991761, 4.92276*10^-24}, {1.53587, 
>     2.17824*10^-23}, {1.16334, 3.45266*10^-22}, {1.04129, 
>     2.0493*10^-22}, {1.11061, 5.22911*10^-23}, {1.12109, 
>     3.29064*10^-22}, {1.42001, 1.50274*10^-22}, {0.810429, 
>     1.04922*10^-22}, {1.03759, 3.54763*10^-22}, {0.0675174, 
>     2.45676*10^-23}, {1.25762, 1.85991*10^-22}, {1.36577, 
>     3.60215*10^-22}, {0.187012, 6.80263*10^-24}, {1.21308, 
>     2.82342*10^-22}, {0.377109, 1.31442*10^-23}, {1.36006, 
>     1.16519*10^-22}, {1.46638, 1.22258*10^-22}, {0.581, 
>     2.34536*10^-23}, {1.40918, 2.62331*10^-22}, {0.388662, 
>     5.97177*10^-23}, {1.4566, 
>     1.68928*10^-22}, {1.20275, -4.79228*10^-24}, {0.170742, 
>     4.5416*10^-23}, {1.37674, 
>     1.86197*10^-22}, {0.116856, -1.00736*10^-23}, {1.22612, 
>     1.5878*10^-22}, {1.20796, 1.48358*10^-22}, {1.50292, 
>     2.21743*10^-22}, {0.288941, 3.02118*10^-24}, {1.54072, 
>     2.4451*10^-22}, {1.39154, 2.77737*10^-22}, {1.23834, 
>     9.00971*10^-23}, {1.39328, 2.74117*10^-22}, {0.798185, 
>     3.32769*10^-23}, {1.13695, 2.77154*10^-22}, {1.17551, 
>     3.4018*10^-22}, {0.255165, 6.47802*10^-23}, {0.833108, 
>     1.79788*10^-22}, {1.52038, 2.32529*10^-22}, {0.594664, 
>     1.56821*10^-23}, {1.03197, 1.58076*10^-22}, {1.16209, 
>     1.94026*10^-23}, {1.43709, 1.5892*10^-22}, {0.144537, 
>     6.16643*10^-23}, {1.19172, 1.7143*10^-22}, {0.982985, 
>     1.34247*10^-22}, {1.3928, 1.58663*10^-22}, {1.23714, 
>     2.31146*10^-22}, {1.30171, 3.35299*10^-22}, {1.05888, 
>     6.41132*10^-24}, {0.838928, 2.16589*10^-23}, {0.140473, 
>     2.02373*10^-23}, {1.50051, 2.03801*10^-22}, {1.46125, 
>     1.29965*10^-22}, {0.798801, 1.19886*10^-22}, {1.16381, 
>     5.73977*10^-23}, {1.41129, 5.8235*10^-23}, {1.32683, 
>     2.7671*10^-22}, {1.49251, 3.6316*10^-22}, {0.998922, 
>     1.84528*10^-22}, {1.34824, 8.25818*10^-23}, {1.50768, 
>     3.63531*10^-22}, {0.911975, 2.69697*10^-22}, {1.46345, 
>     1.03119*10^-22}, {1.4794, 2.96674*10^-22}, {0.0438962, 
>     5.581*10^-23}, {0.612102, 8.20571*10^-24}, {1.00819, 
>     3.15867*10^-22}, {0.959927, 2.38897*10^-22}, {1.3578, 
>     2.79966*10^-22}, {1.53118, 1.63845*10^-23}, {1.13763, 
>     1.31936*10^-23}, {0.204809, 2.97558*10^-23}, {1.03519, 
>     4.95699*10^-23}, {1.06397, 7.64426*10^-23}, {0.864379, 
>     3.56829*10^-22}, {1.09128, 1.253*10^-22}, {1.18188, 
>     2.36625*10^-22}, {0.110789, 8.48675*10^-25}, {1.29772, 
>     4.64425*10^-23}, {1.34315, 3.59015*10^-22}, {0.98371, 
>     2.11943*10^-24}, {1.03039, 1.01599*10^-23}, {1.33334, 
>     3.04623*10^-22}, {1.01244, 1.67186*10^-22}, {1.53261, 
>     2.37627*10^-22}, {0.205102, 3.1101*10^-23}, {1.37167, 
>     1.05575*10^-23}, {1.2682, 2.75746*10^-22}, {0.408281, 
>     5.75466*10^-23}, {0.638207, -4.00144*10^-24}, {0.575597, 
>     7.00535*10^-23}, {0.662761, 7.01533*10^-24}, {1.47188, 
>     2.03075*10^-23}, {1.11243, -4.45446*10^-24}, {1.44426, 
>     1.59039*10^-22}, {1.07095, 7.60414*10^-23}, {1.187, 
>     3.60007*10^-22}, {1.2779, 2.88029*10^-22}, {0.845187, 
>     7.59184*10^-23}, {1.34987, 3.17354*10^-22}, {1.51386, 
>     2.74984*10^-23}, {0.912811, 1.75223*10^-22}, {1.22045, 
>     1.68152*10^-22}, {1.29257, 2.92549*10^-22}, {1.5655, 
>     1.3644*10^-22}, {1.40352, 5.11683*10^-23}, {0.819031, 
>     8.66941*10^-24}, {0.868004, 9.90222*10^-23}, {1.06605, 
>     3.48258*10^-22}, {1.42514, 1.88737*10^-22}, {0.800571, 
>     1.24051*10^-23}, {0.428475, 4.21397*10^-23}, {1.5131, 
>     1.71167*10^-22}, {1.26855, 2.68892*10^-22}, {0.640558, 
>     6.78539*10^-24}, {1.18937, 2.73459*10^-22}, {1.16928, 
>     3.73211*10^-23}, {0.172543, 2.2982*10^-23}, {1.37688, 
>     3.18434*10^-22}, {1.20966, 2.87797*10^-22}, {0.984878, 
>     2.49585*10^-22}, {1.01957, 1.77793*10^-23}, {0.519308, 
>     3.65096*10^-23}, {0.259825, 3.81521*10^-23}, {0.815884, 
>     2.64055*10^-22}, {0.611536, 8.14896*10^-23}, {1.02176, 
>     1.92678*10^-22}, {1.48482, 2.98068*10^-22}, {1.42898, 
>     3.37564*10^-22}, {0.0711665, 1.77152*10^-23}, {1.516, 
>     1.9341*10^-22}, {1.16287, 8.29583*10^-23}, {0.607509, 
>     1.32141*10^-23}, {0.180928, 3.97213*10^-23}, {1.49245, 
>     1.42417*10^-22}, {1.26308, 1.48684*10^-22}, {0.88015, 
>     1.2592*10^-22}, {1.35883, 3.58647*10^-22}, {1.3148, 
>     1.27203*10^-22}, {0.920225, 2.11058*10^-22}, {1.21472, 
>     8.76535*10^-23}, {1.43918, 1.47035*10^-22}, {1.16874, 
>     3.59455*10^-22}, {0.378399, 3.16146*10^-23}, {0.904673, 
>     3.56754*10^-22}, {0.237741, 5.60042*10^-23}, {1.02711, 
>     1.30651*10^-22}, {1.37881, 2.8362*10^-22}, {0.958808, 
>     3.42528*10^-23}, {1.52264, 2.6073*10^-22}, {0.92526, 
>     6.10065*10^-23}, {0.975356, 1.28909*10^-22}, {1.4763, 
>     2.83295*10^-22}, {0.979255, 2.59834*10^-22}, {1.3119, 
>     3.08227*10^-22}, {0.860617, 2.57094*10^-22}, {1.33798, 
>     3.02703*10^-22}, {0.258786, 3.60806*10^-23}, {0.908019, 
>     6.84894*10^-23}, {1.42466, 4.55789*10^-23}, {0.0624634, 
>     3.44774*10^-24}, {1.05236, 1.80613*10^-22}, {0.912111, 
>     2.08829*10^-22}, {1.50892, 6.57823*10^-23}, {0.713348, 
>     3.34005*10^-23}, {0.961332, 8.67782*10^-23}, {1.24796, 
>     3.39559*10^-23}, {1.07109, 1.00147*10^-23}, {0.677877, 
>     4.32398*10^-23}, {1.1723, 1.38528*10^-22}, {0.138594, 
>     3.4843*10^-23}, {1.1722, 2.22223*10^-22}, {0.914249, 
>     7.33992*10^-23}, {0.78159, 7.09012*10^-23}, {1.39159, 
>     3.42175*10^-22}, {0.086278, 5.56734*10^-23}, {1.30074, 
>     2.84227*10^-22}, {1.48533, -8.87987*10^-24}, {1.37504, 
>     3.35381*10^-22}, {0.0913096, 4.19473*10^-23}, {0.59955, 
>     5.00153*10^-23}, {1.18787, 1.67958*10^-22}, {1.39364, 
>     2.69111*10^-22}, {0.748008, 
>     3.11133*10^-22}, {0.553351, -2.90806*10^-24}, {1.45751, 
>     1.90447*10^-22}, {1.38113, 2.4736*10^-22}, {1.26464, 
>     2.74737*10^-22}, {1.04109, 1.21567*10^-23}, {0.133075, 
>     7.50201*10^-24}, {0.986893, 4.0639*10^-23}, {0.754905, 
>     5.53943*10^-23}, {1.10255, 3.0724*10^-22}, {1.30092, 
>     3.05332*10^-22}, {0.766938, 1.99282*10^-22}, {1.05491, 
>     2.48113*10^-22}, {1.39467, 1.75806*10^-22}, {0.0362209, 
>     6.53975*10^-23}, {0.278469, 3.80439*10^-23}, {1.29511, 
>     3.12372*10^-22}, {0.856632, 3.55983*10^-23}, {1.31698, 
>     5.23617*10^-23}, {0.43736, -2.75645*10^-24}, {0.48492, 
>     2.61487*10^-23}, {1.35778, 3.40792*10^-22}, {0.0107749, 
>     7.12025*10^-23}, {0.671119, 4.72035*10^-23}, {1.32664, 
>     3.01369*10^-22}, {1.20288, 2.11251*10^-22}, {0.00855507, 
>     5.67352*10^-23}, {1.3106, 2.81245*10^-22}, {1.36116, 
>     1.49073*10^-22}, {0.804053, 8.75742*10^-23}, {1.15112, 
>     1.20557*10^-22}, {1.38665, 1.71375*10^-22}, {1.01153, 
>     2.14371*10^-22}, {1.52766, 4.05201*10^-23}, {1.43237, 
>     1.48963*10^-22}, {0.774954, 2.9334*10^-23}, {1.44106, 
>     1.23659*10^-22}, {0.230238, 
>     1.24274*10^-23}, {1.55572, -6.47554*10^-24}, {1.14593, 
>     1.73286*10^-22}, {1.1056, 3.19964*10^-22}, {0.268779, 
>     4.80767*10^-23}, {0.0793701, 1.17562*10^-23}, {1.13378, 
>     1.36292*10^-22}, {1.37951, 3.58113*10^-22}, {0.445884, 
>     6.80927*10^-23}, {1.45061, 2.02933*10^-22}, {1.34487, 
>     9.1956*10^-23}, {1.35399, 4.43222*10^-23}, {1.48545, 
>     7.14265*10^-23}, {1.37478, 
>     2.0689*10^-22}, {0.039389, -4.01814*10^-24}, {1.56089, 
>     1.73775*10^-22}, {1.0352, 4.41479*10^-23}}

(this sample is smaller than in the picture)
My aim is to extrapolate the area corresponding to the orange points that don't overlap with the "green" region. Since the overlap is small my idea was to use a PDF for the orange points and the following is a contour plot obtained using

```
Fun = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, Automatic, "Gaussian"];

ContourPlot[PDF[Fun, {x, y}], {x,-0.1, Pi/2}, {y, 0, 2.8 10^-22} ]
```

[image]

Now I would like to take a reasonable region of that plot corresponding to a probability say 95% (of course this region cannot be obtained uniquely).
Is there a solution to find a suitable region of the xy plane corresponding to that probability?

I could simply plot the region for which PDF > "arbitrary value" but this value would depend upon the area itself (since the PDF is almost constant) and would not work well for other sets of data.

**notes**: I need the area in order to perform a 2D integral, so the region should be expressed as a condition for x and y. I might need the same thing for a 4D or 5D integration so I am looking for a method that could work in different dimensions as well.

Comment: You could include a function to generate both point sets or a link to those points already calculated. Generating input data for experimentation in finding an answer is a tax you're imposing to those who may want to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks for your update. I believe both point sets are needed :)

Comment: i believe you copied the wrong data: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lYshZ.png

Comment: Sorry, I edit the question again ;)

Comment: Perhaps something like `f = {#[[1]], #[[2]] 10^22} &; {datar, data2r} = 
 Select[#, 0 < #[[2]] < 2 &] & /@ {f /@ data, f & /@ data2}; Fun = 
 SmoothKernelDistribution[#, Automatic, "Rectangular"] & /@ {datar, 
   data2r}; NIntegrate[
 Boole[PDF[Fun[[1]], {x, y}] Length@datar >= 
   PDF[Fun[[2]], {x, y}] Length@data2r], {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, 2 }]`

Comment: Seems to work only if I remove in the integral Length@datar and actually I don't understand why you use it. Using PDF should "normalize" the hight already.

Comment: Yeah, I was probably overthinking it

Comment: I've modified the last integral: 
  > NIntegrate[
 Boole[PDF[Fun[[1]], {x, y}] >= PDF[Fun[[2]], {x, y}] ] Boole[
   PDF[Fun[[1]],   {x, y}] > 10^-10], {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, 6}]

Also I've found another similar answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20464/how-do-you-draw-credible-regions-intervals-on-a-2d-pdf/20481#20481. Both ways lead to a an estimation of the area but a problem is present in both: when I change the domain of integration (in you case y from 4 to 6) I get a different result. AccuracyGoal and other options don't seems to help.