# MemoryAllocationFailure: Finding 90% Confidence ellipses for 2d PDFs with *tiny* densities

Tags: memory

I'm trying to find a 90% confidence ellipse for a complicated, and *tiny* "Gaussian-esque" PDf. These pdf is the result of many, many ugly marginalizations and transformations so I can't quite list the entire procedure to get here. However, here is the form copy-pasted from the output:

```
PDF=(5.886257374675689*10^-67968602206 E^((
2.14773*10^30 - 7.17192*10^7 Y + 3.3263*10^25 Y^2 - 5.24146 Y^3 + 
    2.41949*10^18 Y^4 + 
    X (-4.55555*10^9 - 8.85499*10^25 Y - 47332. Y^2 - 
       6.4715*10^18 Y^3 - 0.00343484 Y^4) + 
    X^2 (8.83891*10^25 + 44896.7 Y + 6.45974*10^18 Y^2 + 
       0.00328119 Y^3 + 1.42101*10^-24 Y^4))/((1.36831*10^7 + 
      1. Y^2) (1.00293*10^12 - 4.13404*10^7 X Y + 1.54599*10^7 Y^2 + 
      X^2 (4.14512*10^7 + 1. Y^2)))) (8.74222*10^34 + 
     1.86798*10^16 Y + 2.93648*10^30 Y^2 + 3.1085*10^11 Y^3 + 
     2.46373*10^25 Y^4 + 7585.9 Y^5 + 
     X^2 (-4.05503*10^30 + 7.26488*10^11 Y - 6.69839*10^25 Y^2 - 
        115576. Y^3 - 1.45374*10^19 Y^4 - 0.00637899 Y^5) + 
     X^3 (1.01412*10^12 + 8.83891*10^25 Y + 242776. Y^2 + 
        1.07871*10^19 Y^3 + 0.00966282 Y^4 + 1. Y^5) + 
     X (-6.82638*10^16 - 1.88736*10^30 Y - 1.41319*10^12 Y^2 - 
        3.23553*10^25 Y^3 - 42333.8 Y^4 + 
        4.83899*10^18 Y^5)))/((1.36831*10^7 + 1. Y^2) Sqrt[
   9.82773*10^8 + 
    71.8241 Y^2] (1.00293*10^12 - 4.13404*10^7 X Y + 
     1.54599*10^7 Y^2 + X^2 (4.14512*10^7 + 1. Y^2))^2 Sqrt[(
   2.01545*10^12 - 8.30758*10^7 X Y + 3.10675*10^7 Y^2 + 
    X^2 (8.32985*10^7 + 2.00956 Y^2))/(1.36831*10^7 + 1. Y^2)])
```

Notice how there is a Gaussian term, a few polynomial terms, and most importantly a normalization constant of $5.9\times10^{-68,000,000,000}$, wow! And yes, it is properly normalized, i.e:

```
NIntegrate[PDF,{X,-Infinity,Infinity},{Y,-Infinity,Infinity}] (*=1*)
```

And it does create quite a nice contour plot:

[image: contour plot]

However, I'm interested in finding the 90% confidence interval. Following this post (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20481/58658), I try it and get the following errors upon doing the integrals:

```
f[X_, Y_, t_: 0] := With[{z = PDF}, z Boole[z >= t]];
NIntegrate[f[X,Y, t] /. t -> 1, {X, -1, 1}, {Y, -1, 1}] /. t -> 1
```

here for a sample contour height of 1. This gives me the error:

```
Throw: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[..., _SystemException]
```

and output:

```
SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]
```

Oops! I've looked through various other posts and found that it's not really fixable - most people say it's a bug (I don't think that's the case here), or you can find a loophole to work around it.

Note that I have gotten this 90% error ellipse process to work on numerous other cases, such as with PDFs with exponents of around $-1,000,000$, but I guess once it's this large Mathematica struggles. Also, I've tried rescaling my normalization factor to 1, but this in turns scales the contour heights (t) from ~20 to $10^{-68,000,000,000}$, which as you can imagine gives its own set of problems.

Does anyone have any workarounds for finding the 90% confidence interval? Perhaps even an approximation would be extremely useful!!

Thanks so much in advance!
Zack

Comment: It looks like numerical computation with such huge exponents is unreliable; my advice would be to digitize the PDF you've got (given that you can plot it, you can probably easily create an `InterpolatingFunction` to numerically represent it), and work with that numerical PDF for the rest of your calculation.

Comment: I think that some of your problems are related to the enormous numbers you are using.  Can you find a way of getting some of them to cancel.  E.g. moving the factor inside the `Exp` function?